# How to subscribe to an individual field using parsley.js?

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to figure out a way to change css elements upon a field being succesfully validated (with parsley.js).  Below is a response I was given, and I'm not understanding how to accomplish this.

> "A solution is to listen for the right events, either
>   globally or by subscribing on the individual forms or fields. Parsley
>   events: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-overview
>
> You'll probably want the parsley:field:success and parsley:field:error
>   events.
>
> Once you've got an event handler, there are all sorts of strategies
>   available to you using jQuery - you can check for success classes in
>   the elements"

I don't really understand how to accomplish what is being described in the response above.

How can I change a div's display to 'none' upon the succesful validation of a form field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsley has a list of events that are triggered when something happens. You can check the complete [list in the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-list).

Given that you want to hide a div when some field is validated (in reverse you'll want to display the div when the field is not validated) you can use the events `parsley:field:success` and `parsley:field:error` as suggested in the response.

In order to use these events you'll need to listen to them so you can perform some action. You can do that through `$.listen('event:name', callback)` ([usage in docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-usage)).

So what you need is something like this:

```
// Listen to the event triggered when SOME field is validated 
$.listen('parsley:field:success', function(parsleyField) {
    // We need to check what is the validated field
    if (parsleyField.$element.attr('name') == 'some-form-field') {
        // given that this is the field we want, we'll hide the div
        $('#div-to-hide').hide();
    }
});

// This is needed in order to display the div after the field was validated.
// Imagine that the field was validated and then the user changed its content
// and now the field is not valid
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(parsleyField) {
    if (parsleyField.$element.attr('name') == 'some-form-field') {
        $('#div-to-hide').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try this later today and report back.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I tried to make a quick example on codepen.io, my objective is to display the 'checkmark' div when 'messagebox' form field is validated by parsley.  Can you tell me what I did wrong?   http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/vEWLWy

Comment: You had two issues. The first is that you are using `parsleyField.$element.attr('name') == 'messagebox'` when you should have used `attr('id')`. The second is that your `$.listen(...)` is inside the `submit`. You should place the code globally (that is, inside your `(function(){ })`. See this forked codepen: http://codepen.io/milz/pen/wBPMjy